# Google Tag Manager for Windows phone 8

Tags: google-tag-manager

Do we have any SDK for integrating Google Tag Manager for Windows Phone 8 applications?

I could find third party SDK for Google analytics but i could not find any SDK for Google Tag Manager integration. If there is no SDK, do we have any reference implementation / samples for the same?

Comment: I don't believe there are any SDKs available.

Comment: So are there any guidelines or samples to start implementing GTM for mobile apps in general?

Comment: Have you tried looking here? https://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/